# sox mp3 to wav. output wav file is empty

Tags: mp3, wav, output, sox, is-empty

I am trying to convert mp3 file to wav file using sox. But output file is always empty.

I have tried the commands found on following page.

http://stefaanlippens.net/audio_conversion_cheat_sheet
http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/05/sound-exchange-sox-15-examples-to-manipulate-audio-files/

Why the output file is empty? Did i miss any other option?

Thanks

Comment: What's the command you are actually giving?

Comment: I have tried all of these
# Minimal conversion example
sox input.mp3 output.wav
 
# Convert to mono (two possibilities: by specifying output format
# or with the 'channels' effect.
sox input.mp3 -c 1 output.wav
sox input.mp3 output.wav channels 1
 
# Change sample rate (again two possibilities)
sox input.mp3 -r 8000 output.wav
sox input.mp3 output.wav rate 8000
# Newer versions of SoX also support
sox input.mp3 output.wav rate 8k

Comment: sox sample.mp3 sample.wav

works fine if you download the mp3 file from http://www.nch.com.au/acm/sample.mp3

but why its not working for http://soundxx.mp3pk.com/indian/aashiq_banaya_aapne/4(mp3pk.com).mp3